# Reading first array part from text file php

Tags: php, arrays

I am wondering how I can read the first part of my array from a text file. Here is the code:

array.txt

```
 Array
 (
      [0] => something
      [1] => another
      [2] => other
 )
```

The section above is what is on my text file. The file is named array.txt. I want to be able to read the first part of the array which can be identified by the number zero. Here is the code:

```
 $arrayOne = ""; 
 foreach(file('array.txt') as $line) {
      $arrayOne .= $line;
 }

 //echo $arrayOne;
 print_r($arrayOne);
```

The code above reads each line from the file and prints or echos the contents from the file. The issue that I am having is when I try to display my first part of the array, instead of getting `something` I end up getting the first part of the string which is `A`. Here is the code:

```
 echo $arrayOne[0];
 // Outputs: A
```

How can I read the first part from my array?

Comment: It will take each line in a stirng from text file.  So for first line $arrayOne is 'Array'. And $arrayOne[0] will give the first character of the string

Comment: I want to print `something` from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read the file it is only processed as text, it doesn't know that it's an array. Save your file into a JSON format and use php built in function to read JSON.

For Decoding JSON file : php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

For Encoding JSON file : php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: That is not it... I want to echo the first part of the array or section [0]

Comment: I've updated my code. if you only want to get the 2nd line only, just do:  if (counter == 2)

Comment: You only want to print "something"? not the whole line?

Comment: Right I only want to print `something`

Comment: Oh! when you read the file it is only processed as text, it doesn't know that it's an array. Save your file into a JSON format and use php built in function to read JSON. check : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: you could but it will become very tedious and hard to maintain. Once you get the line, you could say that you want all content after "=>" using regex. once again, I would not suggest that. JSON is what you need, it's not hard. it's just format, learn it, you'll be happy you did!

Comment: yes, by using json_encode instead. check: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

it will be good if we are using a json content or simple string content in text file.

This may work for your current requirement.

```
$arrayText = ""; 
 foreach(file('array.txt') as $line) {
      $arrayText .= $line;

 }
 echo $arrayText."<br/>";//Array ( [0] => something [1] => another [2] => other )

 $arrayText = trim($arrayText);
 $arrayText = preg_replace(array('/^Array\s*\(/', '/\)\s*$/', '/\[([0-9]+)\]/'), array('', '', ''), $arrayText);
 echo $arrayText."<br/>";//=> something => another => other 

 $arrData = explode('=>', $arrayText);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrData);
echo "</pre>";
echo $arrData[1];//something
```